# How can I fetch all systemd1 devices?

Tags: python, dbus, freedesktop.org

I wrote the code below to try and detect if a specific device is attached through USB. I'd like to iterate through the attached devices.

```
def scanCameraInterfaces(self):
    ud_manager_obj = dbus.SystemBus().get_object('org.freedesktop.systemd1', '/org/freedesktop/systemd1')
    om = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit')

    try:
        for k, v in om.GetManagedObjects().items():
            print(k)
            print(v)
    except Exception:
        print("No devices found...")
```

However, this will always print "No devices found...". So I removed the `try`, so I could see the error. It throws this: `dbus.exceptions.DbusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules: type="method_call", sender=":1.39" (uid=1000 pid=1009 comm="python3 usbtest.py") interface="org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" request_reply="0" destionation=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init splash ")`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) D-Bus bindings easier to work with.

For example to get a list of all the units with the `*usb*` pattern in them:

```py
import pydbus
systemd = pydbus.SystemBus().get('org.freedesktop.systemd1', '/org/freedesktop/systemd1')
for units in systemd.ListUnitsByPatterns([], ['*usb*']):
    print(units[0])
```

To get a list of all the systemd1 methods using Python:

- `dir(systemd)`

On the command line:

- `busctl introspect org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by the following code:

```
import re
import subprocess
device_re = re.compile("Bus\s+(?P<bus>\d+)\s+Device\s+(?P<device>\d+).+ID\s(?P<id>\w+:\w+)\s(?P<tag>.+)$", re.I)
df = subprocess.check_output("lsusb")
devices = []
for i in df.split('\n'):
    if i:
        info = device_re.match(i)
        if info:
            dinfo = info.groupdict()
            dinfo['device'] = '/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s' % (dinfo.pop('bus'), dinfo.pop('device'))
            devices.append(dinfo)
print devices
```

your output will be:

```
[
{'device': '/dev/bus/usb/001/009', 'tag': 'Apple, Inc. Optical USB Mouse [Mitsumi]', 'id': '05ac:0304'},
{'device': '/dev/bus/usb/001/001', 'tag': 'Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub', 'id': '1d6b:0002'},
{'device': '/dev/bus/usb/001/002', 'tag': 'Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub', 'id': '8087:0020'},
{'device': '/dev/bus/usb/001/004', 'tag': 'Microdia ', 'id': '0c45:641d'}
]
```

if you are working in windows you can try:

```
import win32com.client

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_USBHub"):
    print usb.DeviceID
```